# UIScroll zooming problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a photo ,its size is 1024*768, I added a UIScrollview to the image, the problem is when I zoom everything seemed to be ok till i go to the right or down edges of the photo I see there is a free space under the image, in other words zooming is ok but the image is not zooming and its edges is not connected to the edges of the uiscrollview so I see spaces under and in the right side of the image, if I zoom more the space is getting bigger, here is the code: help me please

```
    scrollASync = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    [imgv setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"11.jpg"]];

    [scrollASync setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scrollASync setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [scrollASync setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
    [scrollASync setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
    [scrollASync setDelegate:self];
    [scrollASync setBounces:YES];
    [scrollASync setBouncesZoom:YES];
    [scrollASync setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [scrollASync setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [scrollASync addSubview:imgv];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollASync];
```

Comment: I'm getting crazy about this error, I'm not figuring out what could be the problem that causes this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Scrollview's delegate method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
 {
       return your imageview;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
imgv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Hope it helps...